# Creating custom url from form parameters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes

I'm currently working on a tool, that takes form input tags and produces a page based on those inputs

my form looks like:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "show", :controller => "tool"}) do %>
  ....
  ....
  ....
<% end %>
```

in my controller I have the show method like so:

```
  def show
    param1 = params[:param1]
    param2  = params[:param2]
    param3  = params[:param3]
    param4  = params[:param4]

    #process params

  end
```

and then I have my show.html.erb to process the show method. For this to work I have in my

routes.rb:

```
  match "/tool" => "tool#index"
  match "/tool/show/" => "tool#show"
```

I want the url to show all the parameters like `/tool/param1/param2/...`  instead of just `/tool/show/`. I tried adding the following to the routes

```
match "/tool/show/:param1/:param2" => "tool#show"
```

but it would mess up because my form is calling only `show`. How would I got about this to create a link with all params using only the method `show`, and the parameters will be generated after the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have your parameters separated by slashes, or is the usual way of doing `GET` parameters OK? For example, like this:

**/posts/5?email=def&message=ghi&name=abc**

You can use your URL helper to make a link like that with code like this:

```
<%= link_to "link text", post_path(name: @post.name, email: @post.email, message: @post.message) %>
```

Comment: sorry, super new to ruby is it possible to show me how did the above using the form_tag? and what would I need to change in my routes.rb ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is your form in your `new.html.erb` view?

Comment: its in index.html.erb and the form is calling show which uses show.html.erb

Comment: Where do your `param1`, `param2`, etc. values come from?

Comment: from the form in index.html.erb and then in the show method I get them and process show.html.erb

Comment: What page should your link take you to? Should it take you to the show page that you're already on?

Comment: it should take me to tool/show ... so I want /tool to take me to `/tool/5?param1=def&param2=ghi&param3=abc`

Comment: `/tool` will take you to `/tool`, `/tool/show` will take you to `/tool/show` and `/anything/else` with take you to `/anything/else`. I am just not following your explanation. You have a form in **index.html.erb**. When you hit the submit button, it sends your `params1`, `params2`, etc. values to the server and calls your `show` action. It doesn't call a `create` action? And does it `POST` the `params*` values?